With rigid bodies, can we compute work done be separate forces separately? If so, how is it calculated?
When calculating the work done on a point particle, we use the following formula:
$W = \int \Sigma\vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr}$
Alternatively, we can also calculate the work done be each of the individual forces acting on the particle, and sum all of these up. For example:
$W_1 = \int \vec{F_1} \cdot \vec{dr}$
$W_2 = \int \vec{F_2} \cdot \vec{dr}$
$W = W_1 + W_2$
The important thing about this second point is, that if we see a force that is always perpendicular to the path travelled by the particle, we can immediately conclude it does no work (which of course matters when figuring out whether energy is conserved or not).
This is all fine and good. Now, I'm having some confusion about non-point, rigid bodies with dimensions.
I know that the following formula computes the work done on a rigid body:
$W_{translational} = \int \Sigma\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$
$W_{rotational} = \int \Sigma\tau d\theta$
$W = W_{translational} + W_{rotational}$
Where $\tau$ is the net torque acting on the object, and $\vec{r}$ is the center of mass of the object.
What I mean by "translational" (excuse my awkward terminology) is the work responsible for moving the object's center of mass. And what I mean by "rotational" is the work responsible for rotating the object around its center of mass.
This again is all fine and good.
Now I'm trying to understand if, similar to the point-mass case, we can can calculate the (translational) work done by the various forces separately, and then sum them up to get the total (translational) work done.
For example:
$W_{1} = \int F_1 \cdot d\vec{r_1}$
$W_{2} = \int F_2 \cdot d\vec{r_2}$
$W_{translational} = W_{1} + W_{2}$
Where $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$ are vectors - either the center of mass, or the respective points of application (which is one of my following questions).
So my questions are:

Can we compute the work done be the forces separately, and then sum them up, as described?

If we can - than what should be the vectors $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$? Are they both the center of mass of the rigid object? Or is each vector the point of application of the associated force at a given moment? If the latter - what if this point changes constantly due to movement of the object (even if the force itself doesn't move or change)?


Thank you

If with $\Sigma\vec{F}$ you actually mean a sum over forces, then you can just split your integral by integrating over each summand individually and then summing up the integrals.

@Zaph I see, doing a line integral over the path of the center of mass for each force, and then summing them. But will it work the same way, if I take the point of contact of each force, instead of the center mass?

I don’t think it would. At least I don’t see why it would right now. If you take the trajectories of the points of contacts of each force you will mix up translational and rotational contributions in a way, that seems to depend on the specific form of your body, because the movement of each point should drag the body with it, and I don’t see right now which kind of terms would be considered correctly and which might not. Maybe I will write an answer later if my mind gets clearer on this.

Technically, work is not given by the integral of the center of mass point (this is known as Pseudowork), the work is given by:
$$W=\sum_i\int\vec F_{i_\text{external}}\cdot d\vec r_i.$$
Thus, as you note in your post, you should add up the individual work done on each particle. In the above equation, $d\vec r_i$ represents the displacement of the $i^{\text{th}}$ particle under the force $\vec F_{i_{\text{external}}}$. The displacement of the point of application of the force is not in general equal to the displacement of the center of mass. However, sometimes, the pseudowork associated with the displacement of the center of mass is equal to the work, so one must pay attention to the specifics of the problem at hand.
For a good discussion see the AJP paper "Pseudowork and Real Work" 1 by Bruce Sherwood.

Thanks, let me see if I understand: suppose I have some rigid body (consisting, of course, of a huge amount of particles). Suppose there are, say, three forces acting upon it at different points of application: F1, F2 and F3. Now, I would like to compute the translational work done on the object.
One approach, would be to take the net force, and take the line integral of the net force over the path traveled by the center of mass.
The other approach: for each force, take the line integral of the force over the path traveled by the point of contact. And then sum the three results.

Will I always get the same result?

@AvivCohn For example, if you have a box with three forces acting on it to create a net translational motion on the box, then you may use the center of mass approach, and yes both approaches will give the same result.

Thanks. Also: suppose that force F1 is acting on a point which is moving in a perpendicular direction to the direction of F1. However - the center of mass of the object is not perpendicular to F1. Does F1 do work?
For example: a ladder is leaning against a wall, and starts to "slide down". There's a normal force from the wall to the ladder, operating on the point of contact between the two.
On the one hand, the point of contact is constantly moving straight down vertically - while the normal is horizontal. So they are perpendicular, and according to this maybe the normal does no work.

However, the normal is not perpendicular to the movement of the center of mass (which moves in some curve). So, does this normal force do work or not? Thanks

@AvivCohn Because the point of contact on which the normal force acts does not move out from the wall, the normal force does no work.
